# access to ArrayList from a different class

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, applet

Hmm... did I miss something?
Trying to draw missiles objects from an ArrayList but keep getting an error NullPointerException when p.missilies.size() called. Missiles are definately there, and instantiated in the Player class, but how do I get access to it from the ActionMissile.class?

ActionMissile class

```
public class ActionMissile {

public ArrayList<Missilies> missilies = new ArrayList<Missilies>();

 public void paint(Graphics g, MainClass mc) {
     url = mc.getDocumentBase();
     missile = mc.getImage(url, "missile.png");
     //missilies = p.getMissilies();
        for (int i = 0; i < p.missilies.size(); i++ ) {
            Missilies m = new Missilies(mc);
            m = (Missilies) p.missilies.get(i);
            g.drawImage(missile, x, y, mc);
        }       
    }
```

Main class

```
ActionMissile a;

public void init()
{
    setSize(800, 600);
    p = new Player(this);
    e = new Enemy(this);
    m = new Missilies(this);
    a = new ActionMissile();

 public void paint(Graphics g){
    p.paint(g, this);
    e.paint(g, this);
    if (!p.missilies.isEmpty())
        a.paint(g, this);       
}
```

Player class

```
  @Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode()){
    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:{

        if (lastKey == null || lastKey != e.getKeyChar()) {
            lastKey = e.getKeyChar();
            Missilies m = new Missilies(x,y);
            m.fire();
            missilies.add(m);
           System.out.println("Missilies "+missilies);
```

Comment: Where is `p` declared in `class ActionMissile`?

Comment: What is `p`? It is never declared in `ActionMissile`.

Comment: p isn't defined. How does this compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
p.missilies.size()
```

To:

```
mc.p.missiles.size()
```

You want to check the missiles in the p of mc.

This looks like it, because you call the method in:

```
if (!p.missilies.isEmpty())
    a.paint(g, this);
```

That code is in mc. The p in that code thus also belongs to mc.